# можно ли ставить в css font-family перед @font-face?

Tags: html, css

Я попробовал вот такой порядок для css (они могут располагаться в разных файлах) и он работает.

Хочу узнать - это вообще правильно и допускается ли такой порядок?
Насколько я могу понять именно на таком принципе работают "оптимизаторы" загрузки шрифтов на js.

```
h2 {
  font-family: 'inconsolatacyrmedium';
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'inconsolatacyrmedium';
   src: url('inconsolatacyr-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('inconsolatacyr-webfont.woff') format('woff');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Можно, т.к. как только будет объявлен (загружен) данный шрифт, он отобразится

Comment: оставьте свой ответ не как комментарий а как ответ, чтобы я принял его. а так - не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стили, шрифты могут быть приняты где угодно, в каком угодно порядке, НО, они смогут быть отображены только в том случае (или тогда), когда они будут загружены на страницу.

К таким элементам относятся картинки, шрифты, шрифты иконки и тому подобное.